# Only one value from array appearing in results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This may be a more complicated question than I realize, but I have no coding experience or training, hence the cryptic title (I don't even know what it's called that I'm doing here.  Something about "looping" is about all I know).  So if 
`foundCValues.push(colCdata[1][i]);` returns the first result in a column that should have multiple results, is the fix as simple as just changing something within the brackets after `colCdata`?  I've tried several variations and none get me where I need to be.  I'd like to either return the entire column, or every value in the column that isn't `NULL`.

Here is the rest of this particular part of the script.  If I need to post the entire script or explain further, please let me know.

```js
    for(var i=0;i<colCdata.length;i++) { 
      if(valueToFind==colCdata[0][i]) {
          foundCValues.push(colCdata[1][i]);  //  Only displays first match
        //  foundCValues.push(colCdata[i][1]);  //  Shows something seemingly random
        //  foundCValues.push(colCdata[1]);  //  Displays everything in a row
      }
```

EDIT: [full script](https://script.google.com/d/1DoRzhWlfCOMyPCoiJB0hu5ppjVUKXWzKBREOq0elRrrHJb0ZL9dqWNXJ/edit?usp=sharing) script is HorizontalDV.gs

Basically, what I'm trying to do is transition from using a helper sheet to populate my data validations to just using a list so that things don't get mixed up if lines are added to a sheet.

You can see the commented out "Populate column C data validations" using the previous "helper sheet" method.  It searches the header row for a match (to the previously selected cell [activecell.value]), and then displays the rest of the column below in the data validation to select from.

```js
function horizontal_dv(e){

  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Items'){  
    var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Items');  
    var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Categories-Concat');
  }
  else if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'materialsData'){  
    var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('materialsData');  
    var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('materialsCategories-Concat');
  }
  else if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'toolsData'){  
    var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('toolsData');  
    var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
    var colBdata = colBss.getRange(2,5,colBss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  }
  else if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'tasksData'){  
    var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksData');  
    var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Categories-Concat');
    var colBdata = colBss.getRange(1,2,1,colBss.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    var colCss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksGroups');
    var colCdata = colCss.getRange(2,2,colCss.getLastRow(),colCss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var colDss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksSubGroups');
    var colDdata = colDss.getRange(3,2,1,colDss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  }

  else if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'tasksToolsRequired'){  
    var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksToolsRequired');  
    var colBss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Categories-Concat');
    var colCss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksGroups');
    var colDss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tasksSubGroups');
  }

  var colAValues = [];  
  var foundBValues = [];  
  var foundCValues = [];  
  var foundDValues = [];  
  var foundEValues = [];  
  var foundFValues = [];  
  var foundGValues = [];  
  var foundHValues = [];  

  var activeCell = activess.getActiveCell();    
  const valueToFind = activeCell.getValue();

  //  Populate column B data validations
  //  Horizontal search 
  //  Search header row and return column below
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var colIndex = colBdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;

    if(colIndex != 0){
      if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
        var colBvalidationRange = colBss.getRange(2, colIndex,colBss.getLastRow()-1);
        var colBvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(colBvalidationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colBvalidationRule);
      }  
    }
  }

  //  //  Populate column C data validations
  //  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Items'){  
  //    if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
  //      activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
  //      var colCIndex = colCdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
  //      if(colCIndex != 0){
  //        if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
  //          var colCvalidationRange = colCss.getRange(3, colCIndex,colCss.getLastRow()-1);
  //          var colCvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCvalidationRange).build();
  //          activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCvalidationRule);
  //        }
  //      }
  //    }

  //  Populate column C data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    Logger.log("valueToFind = " + valueToFind);
    Logger.log("colCdata = " + colCdata);
    Logger.log("colCdata.length = " + colCdata.length);


    for(var i=0;i<colCdata.length;i++) { 
      if(valueToFind==colCdata[0][i]) {
          foundCValues.push(colCdata[1][i]);  //  Only displays first match
        //  foundCValues.push(colCdata[i][1]);  //  Shows something seemingly random
        //  foundCValues.push(colCdata[1]);  //  Displays everything in a row
      }
      Logger.log("colCdata[0][i] = " + colCdata[0][i]);
      Logger.log("colCdata[1][i] = " + colCdata[1][i]);

    }
    Logger.log("foundCValues = " + foundCValues);

    for(var i=0;i<colCdata.length;i++) {
      if(valueToFind==colCdata[i]) {
        foundDValues.push(colCdata[i]);
      }
    }

    if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
      var colCValidationRange = foundCValues;
      var colCValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colCValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colCValidationRule);
      var colDValidationRange = foundDValues;
      var colDValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDValidationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(colDValidationRule);
    }
  }      

  //  Populate column D data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var colDIndex = colDdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
    if(colDIndex != 0){
      if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
        var colDvalidationRange = colDss.getRange(4, colDIndex,colDss.getLastRow()-1);
        var colDvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colDvalidationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colDvalidationRule);
      }
    }
  }

  //  Populate column E data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var colEIndex = colEdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
    if(colEIndex != 0){
      if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
        var colEvalidationRange = colEss.getRange(5, colEIndex,colEss.getLastRow()-1);
        var colEvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colEvalidationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colEvalidationRule);
      }
    }
  }

  //  Populate column F data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var colFIndex = colFdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
    if(colFIndex != 0){
      if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
        var colFvalidationRange = colFss.getRange(4, colFIndex,colFss.getLastRow()-1);
        var colFvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colFvalidationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colFvalidationRule);
      }
    }
  }

  //  Populate column G data validations
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 6 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearDataValidations();
    var colGIndex = colGdata[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;
    if(colGIndex != 0){
      if(activeCell.getValue() != ""){ 
        var colGvalidationRange = colGss.getRange(4, colGIndex,colGss.getLastRow()-1);
        var colGvalidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(colGvalidationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(colGvalidationRule);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use console.log to print out some intermediate values or use vscode or chrome devtools and the javascript debugger to set breakpoints and step through your code and inspect variables. These are valuable skills to learn.

Comment: Don't think we have enough info to answer your question. I would read up on `for` loops for starts. What is the end result you are looking for? What is `valueToFind`?

Comment: `colCdata.length` tells you how many items (indexed from 0 to length - 1) are available for the *first* index of the `colCdata` array. So it'll do you no good to use the index `i` in any position other than `colCdata[i]`. It makes no sense as a second position subscript, because you have no idea at that point how many items (if any) are available there.

Comment: What jumps out to me is your row and column indexes are all mixed up.

For starters, the syntax for array retrieval is `colCdata[row][col]` -- imagine the data in a grid. In your for loop "stop" condition, `colCdata.length` is the number of rows in the grid. So that makes it seem like "i" is moving through your rows. But then in your "match" check, `valueToFind==colCdata[0][i]`, i is being used to select a column instead. That must be at least part of your problem. It might help if you gave an example of the kind of data in this array.

Comment: Ok.  All helpful comments.  I do have a lot of logging in the script, so I've been checking that constantly.  I did finally figure out [row][col], but only a few minutes ago. So now that makes more sense.  I tried to post the rest of the script, but I think it's too long.  I'll have to edit it and remove some irrelevant lines.

Comment: I added the entire script and a link to the script as well.  It's a disaster, but I'm trying to tidy it up. https://script.google.com/d/1DoRzhWlfCOMyPCoiJB0hu5ppjVUKXWzKBREOq0elRrrHJb0ZL9dqWNXJ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proably need to have two counters going for it to display the entire array if you have multiple rows and columns.  Depending on how wide your array and how tall, you may set your limits.  If your data is 5 rows tall:

```
//untested 
for (var q = 0; q < 5; q++) /* counts to height one time for every entire count to 
length*/
{
    for(var i=0;i<colCdata.length;i++) /*counts to length before rolling back to 
height */
    {
     foundCValues.push(colCdata[q][i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Works as is so far!  The only thing I'll have to adjust is that it's also populating with the first row/header.  But I can probably figure that out.  Thank you very much! EDIT: `q = 1` did the trick!

Comment: sweet.  Glad that I could help!

Comment: If you need to create another variable for number of data entries, then you can replace the 5 with that so it offers even more flexibility and updates to the number of data entries at any given time.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using `q < colCdata.length;` and that seems to be working.